# Reversing a Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, list, linked-list

This method right below reverses a doubly linked list with n elements. I dont understand how this really works. I have added comments, please correct me if I am wrong. I am not sure how the traversing process works.

```
 public void reverseDLL( ) {
   Node temp=head; //swap head and tail
   head=tail; // head now points to tail
   tail=temp; //tail points to head
    //traverse the list swapping prev and next fields of each node
  Node p=head; //create a node and point to head

  while(p!=null) //while p does not equal null
    { //swap prev and next of current node
      temp=p.next; // p.next does that not equal null? confusing.
      p.next=p.prev; //this line makes sense since you have to reverse the link
      p.prev=temp; //having trouble visualizing this.
      p=p.next;//advance current node which makes sense
    }
 }
```

Comment: why do you need to reverse DLL this way..Just traverse from behind with tail pointer.

Comment: does it matter? i know this solution works, i just need to understand how it works... i need to visualize whats happening for each traversal.

Comment: every time you are changing the pointer in the reverse direction and you are moving your p to next Node.Can you tell me clearly where you get problem ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's try stepping through the code a few lines at a time.

```
Node temp=head;
head=tail;
tail=temp;
```

Here we are just setting up some variables. We are swapping our head to point to the tail and the tail to the head.

Now we define our starting node. This is our new head that used to be the tail.

```
Node p=head; //create a node and point to head

while(p!=null)
{ 
    temp=p.next;
```

At this point, this is what we are looking at (note: if this is the first iteration, `next` would point to null but that doesn't matter, just assume A is null for that case):
[image]

So we have `next` pointing to A and `prev` pointing to B. We want these to be swapped. To do so, we go ahead and assign `next` to `prev` (which points to B) so now `next` and `prev` both point to B.

```
    p.next=p.prev;
```

Great! We're half way there. Now we have:

[image: Step 2]

Now our last step is to have `prev` point to what `next` used to point to. How are we going to get to it? Luckily, we stored what `next` used to point to (in other words, A) in `temp`. So let's use that to assign `prev`.

```
    p.prev=temp;
```

Alas, we have:

[image]

Now this node has been swapped, and we move on to the next.

```
    p=p.next;
}
```

Rinse and repeat.

All together:

```
Node p=head; //create a node and point to head

while(p!=null)
{ 
    temp=p.next; 
    p.next=p.prev; 
    p.prev=temp; 
    p=p.next;
}
```

Comment: At this point, this is what we are looking at (note: if this is the first iteration, next would point to null but that doesn't matter, just assume A is null for that case):  <--- this is what i was having an issue with but that totally makes sense now.

Comment: Ah, so the first iteration is what's causing you trouble. If you mentally replace the letter `A` with `null` in the image, it should show you that it is ok for it to be `null` because you move forward with `B`.

Comment: when you do p=p.next, how does it go to the next node? does it not traverse towards the right (like in the first iteration how it was null).... meaning there are no nodes in the right.

Comment: `p.next` (or `A`) _used_ to be null. If you look at the final image, you will see that by the time we get to `p=p.next`, `p.next` points to `B`, which might or might not be null.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you.

```
struct node* current = head;
struct node* next;
struct node* prev = NULL;



while (current != NULL)  //traverse the whole linked list 
{
   next  = current->next;  //temporarily store the next node
   current->next = prev;    //now assign the prev!node to next of current node
   prev = current;   //update the previous pointer
   current = next;  //update the current pointer

}
```

Look at this figure.
[image]

Hope you get it.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't update the `prev` property. Remember this is a double linked list.

Answer (score 1):

It's just swapping the prev and next pointers in every element of the list. So your comment is correct. The new head's next pointer does start as null. And it gets copied to its prev pointer. As the head of the list its prev should of course be null.

Vj shah's answer does the same thing just with different code.

Comment: yeah. I just made it clear with the diagram what warpstar wanted.

Answer (score 1):

With a Header Doubly Linked List, following is what I understand. Does this help? Is this correct?

The loop may be broken out when current is one node behind tail, but for simplicity, let it reach the tail. 
Also, the usual checks for 0 or 1 sized list come before running the loop.

```
H   1   2   3   4   5   //current pointer at head
*

H   5   1   2   3   4   //bring current tail to the next of current pointer. Update current tail.
*

H   5   1   2   3   4   //advance current pointer to next
    *

H   5   4   1   2   3   //bring current tail to the next of current pointer. Update current tail.
    *

H   5   4   1   2   3   //advance current pointer to next
        *

H   5   4   3   1   2   // and so on.. 
        *

H   5   4   3   1   2
            *

H   5   4   3   2   1
            *

H   5   4   3   2   1
                *

H   5   4   3   2   1
                *

H   5   4   3   2   1   //break out when current pointer is at the tail. 
                    *
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be started from head node also for simplicity, otherwise the algorithm remains the same:

```
Node currentNode=head;

while(currentNode!=null){
    Node temp = currentNode.next;
    currentNode.next=currentNode.prev;
    currentNode.prev=temp;
    currentNode=currentNode.prev;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to how this reversal works is see what a simple doubly linked list looks like before and after it is reversed.  Once you see what needs to happen to reverse the list, the method will be easier to understand.

Suppose you had a `Nodes` like this with the first node at 0:

```
node       0    1    2    3    4
data       A    L    I    S    T
next       1    2    3    4   null
prev      null  0    1    2    3
```

Traversing the nodes above starting at 0 gives the output: ALIST

Leaving the data of each each node in place, you can reverse the list by swapping the
prev and next node values for each node:

```
node       0    1    2    3    4
data       A    L    I    S    T
next      null  0    1    2    3
prev       1    2    3    4   null
```

Traversing the nodes above starting at 4 gives the output: TSILA

The code to do this is simple assuming you have a Node class as such:

```
public class Node {
    private char ch;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;
}

public static Node reverse(Node trav) {
    Node swapped;
        while (trav != null) {
            swapped.next = trav.prev;
            swapped.prev = trav.next;
            trav = swap;
            trav = trav.prev;  // it was swapped so you need to follow prev
            }
        return trav  // return the new head node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void reverseList(){

    Entry<E> refEntry = header.previous;
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
        Entry<E> first = header.next;
        first.next.previous = first.previous;
        first.previous.next = first.next;

        first.previous = refEntry;
        first.next = refEntry.next;
        refEntry.next.previous = first;
        refEntry.next = first;
    }
    refEntry.previous = header;
}
```

The algorithm basically maintains a `pointer(refEntry)` to the entry which is going to be the first element in the list after reversal.

The first element of the list is then removed in iterations and added after the `refEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

My version without recursion that I wrote in Java
Idea behind: Reach the end of list first, mark this node as new head, then start moving backwards direction by flipping connections/Links (next, prev) till you have left no more node.

```
 Node Reverse(Node head) {
        //If List is empty or having one node
        if (head == null || head.next == null) return head;

        //Else
        Node current = head;

        //First move to the end of list
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        //Shift head at tail of list
        head = current;

        //Let the magic begin
        while (current != null) {
                Node prev = current.prev;
                current.prev = current.next;
                current.next = prev;
                current = prev;
        }


        return head;
    }
```

I hope it helps.