# Simpler approach to "reversing a doubly linked list" does not work for some reason

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am aware that "Reversing a doubly linked list" has been asked and answered before, e.g.: 
[Reversing a Doubly Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166968/reversing-a-doubly-linked-list)
But my question a little different.

All the methods that I could find online use a "current node (`curr`)" iterator and do the swapping on that as follows:

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
    Node* curr=head;
    while(curr)
    {
        swap(curr->next, curr->prev);
        head=curr;

        curr=curr->prev;
    }
    return head;
}
```

where the node is of type:

```
struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev
}
```

Now the question is, I tried to simplify that code by omitting the `curr` iterator since it looks totally unnecessary to me. Here is the new code:

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        swap(head->next, head->prev);

        if(head->prev) head=head->prev;
    }
    return head;
}
```

This works on paper however When I test it in an online compiler I get time limit exceeded error: http://www.mycodeschool.com/problems/reverse-a-doubly-linked-list

I believe that we can make all the swapping on the head node and then iterate it to the prev node.

Do you see any logical problems with this code?

Comment: The only time you modify `head` is when `head->prev` is non-null, i.e. `while(head)` will loop forever unless it starts out as null.

Comment: You are missing one version between "on paper" and "online compiler": running the code in a debugger so you can execute it step by step and check that it matches your "on paper" understanding. This is a skill worth a lot more than programming itself.

Comment: To add to @Marc Glisse's very useful comment, printlining is also useful for simple code and would have told you what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        swap(head->next, head->prev);

        if(head->prev) head=head->prev;
        else break;  // !!!
    }
    return head;
}
```